# Computing the the exterior derivative of the connection matrix on a hermitian vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

If $D$ is the Chern connection on a holomorphic hermitian vector bundle $(E,h)$ and $e$ is a holomorphic frame, then $$\vartheta=\partial h \cdot h^{-1}$$ where $h_{ij}=h(e_i,e_j)$. Here $\vartheta$ is the connection matrix and $\partial h$ means the del-derivative of the matrix $h$.

I was going through the following calculation

$$
\begin{align*}
d\vartheta &= (\partial+\bar{\partial})\vartheta =\bar{\partial}\vartheta+\partial(\partial h\cdot h^{-1})= \bar{\partial}\vartheta-\partial h \wedge \partial h^{-1}\\
&= \bar{\partial}\vartheta + \partial h\wedge h^{-1}\partial hh^{-1} = \bar{\partial}\vartheta + \partial hh^{-1}\wedge\partial hh^{-1}.
\end{align*}
$$

I don't see where the last three equalities come from, firstly why do we have

$$
\bar{\partial}\vartheta+\partial(\partial h\cdot h^{-1})= \bar{\partial}\vartheta-\partial h \wedge \partial h^{-1},
$$

is this an application of the Leibniz rule? Secondly why does this equal

$$
\bar{\partial}\vartheta-\partial h \wedge \partial h^{-1}=\bar{\partial}\vartheta + \partial h\wedge h^{-1}\partial hh^{-1}
$$

and

$$
\bar{\partial}\vartheta + \partial h\wedge h^{-1}\partial hh^{-1} =\bar{\partial}\vartheta + \partial hh^{-1}\wedge\partial hh^{-1}?
$$

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you did this calculation by writing the matrices in terms of indices and work with scalar instead of matrix-valued forms.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to work through these several questions you have about Chern connections, since I also find the writings of complex geometry hard to follow. But this question is clear enough. Let me answer this one first.

So all your questions boils down to the following sequence of identities with the reasons listed in the same line.
\begin{align*}
&\quad\partial(\partial h\cdot h^{-1}) \\
&= \partial(\partial h)\cdot h^{-1} - \partial h\cdot \partial h^{-1} \quad\text{graded product rule: } \partial(\alpha\wedge\omega)=\partial\alpha\wedge \omega + (-1)^{\deg \alpha}\alpha\wedge \partial\omega\\
&= 0 - \partial h\wedge \partial h^{-1}\quad\quad \partial^2=0\\
&= \partial h\wedge h^{-1}\partial hh^{-1}\quad \text{derivative of inverse matrix: } \partial h^{-1} = -h^{-1}\partial hh^{-1}\\
&=\partial hh^{-1}\wedge \partial h h^{-1}\quad \text{associativity of matrix multiplication: }A(BC) = (AB)C.
\end{align*}